# Is it possible to send packet under other node's IP?

Tags: networking, ip, mac-address, arp

I have 3 machines on my network

192.168.2.1 => pfSense Router ( 00:0c:29:d4:1f:88 ) 
192.168.2.2 => My Kali Machine ( 00:0c:29:20:f8:0a ) 
192.168.2.11 => Linux ( 00:0c:29:1a:b0:f0 ) 
What I tried to do was to send an ARP request to pfSense at 192.168.2.1 from my Kali Machine, impersonating Linux at 192.168.2.11.

I did the following using Scapy - 
[image]

I set 
 **Source IP as Linux's IP 

Source MAC as Linux's MAC 

Dest. IP as pfSense's IP**

and Surprisingly, It Works As - 
[image]

as you can see, It works! with the actual Sender's ( KALI's ) IP or MAC not being visible at all...
I'm still new in networking so Can anyone explain this to me, how is this possible ? and isn't this a serious Fatal flaw ? any device can pose as any other one ?

Comment: Does your network have anything that would make it impossible?

Comment: ARP Poisoning Is kinda different... Wireshark alerts you by saying Duplicate Use Of MAC Found... In My Case, It doesn't

Comment: Ah, you’re right. You’re just doing (source) MAC address spoofing. Nothing special about it. Ethernet is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARP protocol itself does not provide any methods of protection from
spoofing attacks or of authenticating ARP replies.
Some methods and software do exist to protect against
malicious requests or answers, but they require specific installation
and setup.

Many ARP requests and answers are done by broadcast messages to the entire
network, which is the reason (I think) that nobody bothered with such
protective methods when composing the ARP standard.

References :

- Wikipedia
  [Address Resolution Protocol (ARP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)
- [Understanding How ARP Works](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/concept/ip-arp-understanding.html)

Comment: if this can be done with arp, cant it be done with other protocols too ? i mean, I could up an ICMP packet just like that
... making it look like Linux pinged pfSense but instead it would've Kali ...

Comment: Perhaps - this requires posting a question about each protocol.